# how to present graph with query results in orientdb

Tags: graph, orientdb

I am newbie to orientdb.

I want to know how to show the node/edge graph in the figure with query results. 
I search online for it, however, I still can not find clue.

Answer (score 2):

Use the OrientDB studio:

1. start OrientDB as server
2. Connect to http://localhost:2480
3. Execute your query in the "query" tab
4. Get an item and click on "Graph" tab

Comment: I follow the steps in http://odino.org/graph-in-php-through-orientdb/, however, it is not working. I get the query results, but when I click Graph tab, it only shows one node. I do not know the reason.   Another question is how to get this graph from external REST API?

Comment: Try using function "Send to graph" (small blue circle icon in the top-right corner of the result box). It will show you all results in the graph view. You can follow edges by hovering arrows (incoming and outcoming) and clicking the name of the edge.